# How to retrieve queue from aws SQS using laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am connecting AWS SQS FIFO Queue in Laravel , I want to retrieve queue from AWS SQS with Laravel.
Here is my env  file

```
    QUEUE_CONNECTION=sqs
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=RRKKKAKIAWY7CM4EBHHHH
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=qN25sCiUvrArRdtF+HWbL6zdXFK6lo5SR563
    AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1
    SQS_PREFIX=https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/465941881099
    SQS_QUEUE=NewTestNotificationQueue
    AWS_BUCKET=
```

I  installed composer require aws/aws-sdk-php
and using Laravel Framework 7.30.4
But while executing php artisan queue:listen I am getting error as
follows

```
    [2021-10-06 12:23:09][47e7f3ca-12cf-4f83-b2c3-0dd6942f156e] 
    Processing:
    [2021-10-06 12:23:09][47e7f3ca-12cf-4f83-b2c3-0dd6942f156e] 
   Failed:
```

Can you help ....

my job class

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class listenSQS implements ShouldQueue
{
  use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, 
  SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {  
    

    }

}
```

Can you please help the above is my job class

Comment: What is in your error log? Usually that means your job has failed executing

Comment: [2021-10-06 11:49:53] local.ERROR: Target class [] does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException(code: 0): Target class [] does not exist. at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\awsq\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php:811)
[stacktrace]

Comment: Can i see your job class?

Comment: Include it in the question, fully please hard to read comments

Comment: I have put it in question please

Comment: What is the file name of your job class?

Comment: Job class name  - listenSQS

Comment: But is the file name the same as your class name? and does your job literal nothing atm?

Comment: Yes filename , class name both are  same - listenSQS